# Why would a computer reboot when sending the screen to sleep/standby?

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep

In Windows 10, System, Energy I have set the screen to be switched off after 5 minutes. (PC Standby after 2 hours). 
This happens: After 5 minutes the PC reboots.
There appears to be a direct connection because the PC reboots after x minutes of inactivity where x is the number of minutes I set for the screen.

What could cause this behaviour? How could I fix it?

Almost the same happens when I send the PC to standby manually: It seems to shut down, screen goes black. When I then wake it via the power button it reboots.

This is on a newly built and installed machine, Windows 10, Gigagbyte H310M S2H with a Dell P2416D Screen.

I have no idea where to look next and I don't know if this matters: When powering up (cold start) the PC will not wake up the screen. I need to do a manual reset (button on PC) in order to get the screen display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

1. Go into the BIOS
2. In the 'Power' tab enabele 'CEC 2019'.

That's how easy it can be. And who cares if it sounds far-fetched if it works, right?